# Is it possible to get response with highlighted "_source" instead of "highlight" collection?

Tags: elasticsearch

It would be nice in some cases (I have fixed amount of fields to display on search result and to create logic that would replace one field from "highlight" collection and the second one leave original is somehow uncomfortable). Is it possible?

```
"hits": [
     {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "Company",
        "_id": "da8b8f36-3454-4120-9194-e5355819bff4",
        "_score": 1.214946,
        "_source": {
           "id": "1",
           "name": "The <em>Company</em>"
     }
```

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, since highlighting is a feature available with the search api but doesn't replace your search results.

You need to get the snippets from the highlighted results, and fall back to the `_source` if there are no snippets available for the fields you are interested in. The recently introduced `no_match_size` parameter might be useful to you though, as it allows to include in the highlighted results the first part of a field if there was nothing to highlight, so that the fallback is effectively done by elasticsearch itself internally.

Comment: Thanks. I think, that string positions of highlights would be the most comfortable solution from elasticsearch. That would also solve "encoded issue" when you need to search and display user input.

Comment: If you mean that you would like to make the snippets yourself getting back a the terms and their positions, you might want to have a look at the [term vector api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-termvectors.html), available since 1.0 beta1.

Comment: How do you get `no_match_size` to work with arrays? It still only returns the highlighted values.